# Getting particular nested items from JSON (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, json

If I have a json string as below, what's the best way to get the first iteration of the name (bob) in objective-c?

```
{
    "users": [
        {"id": "1", "name": "bob"},
        {"id": "2", "name": "john"},
        {"id": "3", "name": "joe"}
    ]
}
```

BTW, I'm currently using JSONKit to parse the json string. For example,
NSDictionary *users = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];

Comment: That JSON isn't valid. JSON can only have a single outer object. Should it be wrapped in `[]`?

Comment: I would suggest you consider Apple's `NSJSONSerialization` which has existed since iOS 5. One less dependency.

Comment: This is blazingly simple:  You have an "object" (dictionary) containing one element named "users".  That one element is an array.  The array elements are objects/dictionaries containing two elements.  What have you tried??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first thing to do is drop any third party frameworks for JSON. There is now a native JSON class...

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *users = dictionary[@"users"];
```

Once you've done this you can iterate the `users` array like you would any other array.

Each object in the `users` array is an `NSDictionary` with keys `@[@"id", @"name"]`

e.g.

```
for (NSDictionary *userDict in users) {
    NSLog(@"User name = %@", userDict[@"name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "users" container is a `NSDictionary`, and this is an *unordered* associative container.

That is, strictly, there is no "first" element (a user). Of course, you can iterate with fast enumeration and get a first user, however which one is "implementation defined" (and since the implementation is not public, we do not know which one).

Edit:

Since now, after your edit, your "users" container is an array, the things change dramatically ;)  Someone else give an answer.